# Find out series index using comparable

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreechart to construct a StackedXYAreaChart. I am adding annotations to the chart. To get the X and Y values of the object, I need the series index and item number.

Is there anyway I can get the series index using the comparable key? I am constructing a dynamic chart and I do not the series index prior to running the program.

Comment: Can you query the model, e.g. `dataset`?

Comment: I got it in a different manner. I got the actual X and Y values using my axes. Thank you anyway @trashgod